Is this derivation of decoupling of a quadratic form valid?
I'm trying to get a concentration inequality for $$\sum_{(i,j) \in ([k] \times  [k])}{A_{I_{i}I_{j}}}$$ where $A$ is a fixed $n \times n$ matrix, and $I$ is a uniformly randomly chosen sequence of $[n]$ of length $k$.
This can be formulated as a concentration inequality on the quadratic form $x^tAx$ where we take $x$ to be the indicator function of $I$. Or you would be able to do this if $I$ couldn't have repeats.
Usual concentration inequalities on quadratic forms assume independence of coordinates or normality or some other such condition, so I can't apply them here.
It seems that a standard first step to deriving such an inequality is
a decoupling step, i.e: replacing $x$ with an identically distributed $x'$ on one side of the quadratic form.
We order our I, and then use independent bernoulli selectors $\delta_{1},...,\delta_{k}$ with $p=\frac{1}{2}$, and let $L$ be the set of $i$ such that $\delta_{i} = 1$.
$\sum_{(i,j) \in ([k] x  [k]),i \neq j}{A_{I_{i}I_{j}}} = 4E_{\delta}\sum_{i \neq j} \delta_{i}(1-\delta_{j})a_{I_{i}I_{j}} = 4E_{L}[\sum_{(i,j) \in L \times L^{c}} a_{I_{i}I_{j}}] $
Then since $I_{i}$ is independent of $I_{j}$ for $(i,j) \in L \times L^{c}$, because $I$ has no repeats, we can replace the RHS with $4E_{L}[\sum_{(i,j) \in L \times L^{c}} a_{I_{i}K_{j}}] $ where $K$ is drawn independently of $I$.
Is this valid so far? Is there a better way of working towards getting a concentration inequality on the sum above?

What kind of order relationship do you assume between $k$ and $n$? I mean, do you impose conditions like $1\ll k\ll n$ or $k\asymp n$ or $k\gg n$?

@SangchulLee I am taking here k roughly to be on the order of n. So I suppose the second case. In the toy case I am looking at currently, I have k = 8, and n = 26.
